On VS Code on macOS, how to have multiple instances of merged windows open?
Based on this question, it is possible to merge multiple vs-code projects into a single window on mac using "Window > Merge all windows".
Can we have two windows open with multiple projects in each?
"Merge all windows" doesn't help here as that would merge all open projects into a single merged window.

This is possible by using the "New Window Tab" command that opens a new window  tab in the same window
